# Javascript Function Undefined On Return

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

When I run the function getCoordinates and console.log the two variables I want, the function works as planned and shows: `30.4190671 -97.74594990000003` in the console. Here is the wowrking code...

```
getCoordinates("5401 Duval Austin TX")

function getCoordinates (address) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var coordinatesA;
    var coordinatesB;
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address}, function (results, status) {
    coordinatesA = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
    coordinatesB = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
    console.log(coordinatesA, coordinatesB)
    })
};
```

However, when I add the `return` line at the end of the function in order to work with the data. And I `console.log(getCoordinates("5401 Duval Austin TX"))`
I get `undefined` here is the full code block:

```
console.log(getCoordinates("5401 Duval Austin TX"))

function getCoordinates (address) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var coordinatesA;
    var coordinatesB;
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address}, function (results, status) {
    coordinatesA = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
    coordinatesB = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
    return coordinatesA + coordinatesB
    })
};
```

What gives?

Comment: Try with callback function

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out Asynchronous vs Synchronous here I think, but don't have a great idea of how to use a callback